# Помещения торгового центра

Tags: названия

Можно ли проход в торговом центре, вытянутое помещение, по сторонам которого расположены магазины, имеющиеся на каждом этаже и занимающие большую часть пространства торгового центра, назвать пассажем, галереей?

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

**Пассаж** (от франц. *passage* - **проход**) - крытая **галерея** с торговыми помещениями по обеим сторонам, имеющая выходы на параллельные улицы.

*Петербургский "Пассаж".*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]